# Gain of a dual gate MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, rf, radio, mixer

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHicm1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the schematic of the circuit.  I tried to find the gain of this circuit, assuming 50 % of the duty cycle for the LO, and M2 working on the saturation region, but I don´t know how to proceed exactly after that. My attempt was define VRF = Vgs(1+gm2Ron1)

Comment: If M2(the upper FET) works in sat-region, then that current is controlled by the lower FET.

Comment: i think you will find your answer if you look up a cascode amplifier which is the name for this configuration, not dual gate mosfet

Answer (score -1):

In order to find a simple expression that highlights the dependence of gm on the DC drain we neglect leakage:
\$
g_m =2I_D\sqrt {\dfrac {W}{D}μ_nC_{ox}}=\dfrac{2I_D}{V_{GS}-V_{GS_{Th}}}\$

Then Vrf gain is \$g_{m2}\dfrac{Rd}{2R_{On_1}}\$.

I think...

Comment: Yes, just regard the lower Fet as a switch, on or off.  If it’s on half the time, the upper Fet  gain is half of what a normal common source would give you.

Comment: No this is not a switch, the lower is a Local Oscillator input for a mixer  RF x LO = IF out